# use jquery clone statement to duplicate a div tag and when working with the newly duplicated div, js does it incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jquery's clone statement, duplicates a div tag, but the js statement working with the previously written inner tags doesn't work properly with that newly duped div tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="sona-icon-selected">
      <a class="btn-select-icon">Click to show icons</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sona-icon-selector">
      <p>
      Please, select an icon you want!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="panel">
    <div class="sona-icon-selected">
      <a class="btn-select-icon">Click to show icons</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sona-icon-selector">
      <p>
      Please, select an icon you want!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">
    <a class="btn_clone">Clone Panel</a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.panel').each(function(){
    var $$ = $(this),
        $selected = $$.find('.sona-icon-selected'),
        $btn_show = $$.find('.btn-select-icon'),
      $selector = $$.find('.sona-icon-selector');
  $btn_show.off('click').on('click', function(){
    $selector.slideToggle();
  });
});
$('.panels').each(function(){
  var $$ = $(this), $btn_clone = $$.find('.btn_clone');
  $btn_clone.off('click').on('click', function(){
    var $newPanel = $$.find( '.panel:last' ).clone( true );
    $newPanel.insertAfter($$.find( '.panel:last' ));
  });
 });
```

Full code in jsfiddle.net:
[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/codedaihungmedia/017cg4ba/75/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are corrected code. Fiddle demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjgw70hu/)

```
$('.btn_clone').on('click',function(){
  var $newPanel = $('.panels').find( '.panel:last' ).clone( true );
  $newPanel.insertAfter($('.panels').find( '.panel:last' ));
 $('.btn-select-icon').off('click').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('.panel').find('.sona-icon-selector'));
    $(this).closest('.panel').find('.sona-icon-selector').slideToggle();
 });
```

});

```
$('.btn-select-icon').on('click',function(){
        console.log($(this).closest('.panel').find('.sona-icon-selector'));
        $(this).closest('.panel').find('.sona-icon-selector').slideToggle();
  });
```